# Angular eventemitter not working when emitting the event from directive

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, eventemitter

appcomp.html

```
`<app-child (callemit) = parentFunc($event)> </app-child>`
```

appcomp.ts

`

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.comp.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  ngOnInit() {}
  parentFunc(event){
    console.log(event)
  }
}
```

`

childcomp.html

`<a href='' [mydirective]="val"> </a>`

childcomp.ts

`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './app.child.component.html'
})
```

`

mydirective.ts

`

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Output, HostListener, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[myDirective]'
})
export class myAppDirective {
    constructor() {}
    @Input ('myDirective') val: string;
    @Output() callEmit = new EventEmitter();
    @HostListener('click')
    onClick() {
     event.preventDefault();
     this.callEmit.emit({event , val});
    }
}
```

`
In the above code i am trying to call parentFunc from appcomp using eventemitter and not able to get this work. Please let me know what is wrong here.

Comment: Your above code will emit the value from directive to child component only..! Then you need to emit it again to the parent component.

Comment: Do you have working stackblitz for this scenario?

Comment: is there any other alternative to emit to parent component ? @RohitSharma

Comment: @ng-suhas, there is no working stackblitz. I will see if i can create one to reproduce this

Comment: @Raji eventemitter should be working fine. If you have a stackblitz it will be easy to debug

Comment: Can you please provide some context on why you've created this directive and what is it expected to do?

Comment: @SiddAjmera it will just emit the event on click. I have to emit this event in mulitple child components so created a directive for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you most call callEmit on child component

childcomp.html

```
<a href='' [mydirective]="val" (callEmit)="childFunc($event)"> </a>
```

and in child Component emit the CallEmit Which called from appComp

childcomp.ts

```
@Output() callEmit = new EventEmitter();

childFunc(){
this.callEmit.emit();
}
```

and finally use

appCom.html

```
`<app-child (callemit) = parentFunc($event)> </app-child>`
```

appcom.ts

```
 parentFunc(event){
    console.log(event)
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-exxhms

Comment: thanks. Yes this is one way of doing it. I am trying to know if there is any other alternative for emitting to parent component

Comment: @Raji If you used the directive in the parent component you can able to capture the event. Basically, wherever the directive is used you can able to capture that event.

Comment: That's fine! Please accept @Mostafa's answer if it solved your problem!

Comment: How to make `EventEmitter` subscription work for base directive in the inherited directive?

Comment: The selector is wrong. Try use a example below:

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='#' mydirective (callEmit)="childFunc($event)">Try it on component</a>
```